# Using Azure Devops to distribute power bi reports to our customers

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I am working on a Azure devops solution to distribute and update power bi reports to customers. What I want is to use Devops in the whole lifecycle from DEV, TEST/QA and distribute to Customer PROD. The PROD can be a set of customer's power bi services, where Devops distributes all reports and shared datasets to them.

First I have taken ideas and inspirations from several blogs like this one https://adatis.co.uk/power-bi-ci-cd-with-devops-yaml-pipelines/?unapproved=840&moderation-hash=e57fa5beda7f026acad89029461b9f4a#comment-840

The solution inthis blog is a good start, but does have some limitations to my work. First it is based on only one shared dataset and I must configure devops when new reports are created. It also misses the PROD part but here I can duplicate QA. The only thing about Prod is that I want a set of PRODS. I was hoping I could create a grouped PROD Stage where I could set a variable settings to each of the customers. I am not so well known with Devops so perhaps this solution is there already I hope. To upload new and changed reports and rebind the shared datasets to the updated reports are done by powershell scripts during the steps in the Stage. I hope it is more clear what my challenge is here and also hope you can give me some advise how to solve this.

The lazy way is of course to reuse this solution to overcome my requirement having more than one shared dataset (In my case, a power bi desktop file must point to Azure analysis services, right now it is a sql azure db), is to duplicate the task per shared dataset. Else I have to rewrite the powershell script :-|

To summarize, for each Stage, I need to update a set of variables so DEV, TEST and PROD points to the right servers, databases/aas and other settings. Hopefully I could refresh the reports from devops as well

One more thing is branding. All standard reports will follow the same report layout, but with different branding, perhaps company icon and a background. Is there a way to automate branding in the reports in PROD stage?

Thanks for reading

regards Geir F

Comment: This question is very broad. How do you currently distribute the Power BI Reports?

Comment: Did you mean using azure devops release pipeline to distribute pi reports. How was the DEV/QA step configured currently.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will go back and clarify my situation.